# how to align multiple line to single line in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, notepad

i have Muptiple line text in notepad (more than 10,000).

my java program assign all text to single String

```
EX:
String text="here big text"
```

after copy  the notepad text assign to

```
String text="...
...
...
...
...
..
n line"
```

i got above format

how to change multiple line text to single  line.

Available at any eclipse shortcut or any way

Comment: Do you want to see the text as one line?

Comment: off course .i  need all line in single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse

```
Windows/Preferences/Java/Editor/Typing/ "Escape text when pasting into a string literal"
```

Comment: In your eclipse their is one menu called window in that Preferences after clicking on preferences one dialog will come type there java editor

Answer (score 2):

Use '+' operator and format it in eclipse.It will treat it as a single line.

Comment: i know this but 10,000 lines taking more times.

Comment: if all the lines in the notepad is in single line then ctrl +A and paste the lines inside "". Format it in eclipse [ctrl+shift+F]. you will get it in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text and make a Find/Replace with the "Regular expressions" option checked and replace:

\R

for:

" +\R"

This will facilitate the work.